# Casperjs popup not found by waitForPopup()

Tags: casperjs

waitForPopUp() function does not seem to be identifying the popup from 'this.popups' if there is a `<deleted>` entry in 'this.popups' before the actual popup.

I have a main form in which one can create new data by clicking on a popup link. User creates new data on the popup window. User saves on the popup and it closes and also the main form is refreshed.

Trying to automate this for multiple new data entries. The problem is it works perfectly for the first time but then it errors out at waitForPop() on the second time. It gives the error that popup did not appear in the timeout (5 sec).

```
casper.waitForPopup(/add_new_tasks/, function () {
    /* code */
});
```

I added the following code before this waitForPopup() to call the findByRegExp() function directly.

```
this.wait(2000, function () {
    this.echo("popup list entries - "+this.popups.list());
    this.echo("search popup " + this.popups.findByRegExp(/add_new_tasks/));
});
```

For the **first time** following are the messages -

```
popup list entries - http://blahblah/tasks/add_new_tasks.do?popupMode=true
search popup WebPage(name = "WebPage")
```

For the **second time** following are the messages -

```
popup list entries - <deleted>,http://blahblah/tasks/add_new_tasks.do?popupMode=true
FAIL Error: cannot access member `url' of deleted QObject
```

Casperjs version is 1.1. Phantomjs - 1.9.7. Have tried on phantom 1.9.8 and 1.9.2. Windows 8.1 OS.

I have added popup created, loaded and closed events and can see this.popups array getting updated properly. For the second time the created and loaded events are fired.

Any pointers to what I can do to workaround this, or anything i am doing incorrectly. Thanks...